AG Grid Custom Tool Panel - catch Grid Ready Event
I have a custom tool panel I have implemented that allows users to save the column and filter state to browser localStorage with a user defined name, and also to select among a list of names to reload those column and filter settings. This is all working fairly well.
The issue is, I would like users to be able to select a saved 'view' and flag it as an 'Initial View' that will be automatically selected upon page load.
The problem I am running into is that the grid is not ready, when I try to apply the column and filter states, and I have not yet determine how to catch either the 'GridReadyEvent' or 'FirstDataRenderedEvent', from within the Tool Panel.
I am not sure how (or if) I can add an event listener to the grid from the custom tool panel itself. My current attempts are not working.
For example:
agInit(params: GridStateMgrToolPanelParams): void {
  this.params = params;
  this.params.api.addEventListener("GridReadyEvent", () => {
    console.log("from GridStateMgrToolPanel: grid ready");
  });
}


The following works, but causes a jump of the row data, since the filter is applied after the grid is loaded with its unfiltered data.
agInit(params: GridStateMgrToolPanelParams): void {
  this.params = params;
  this.storeName = `grid-state-mgr-${this.params.storage_key}`;
  this.gsmStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.storeName));
  if (this.gsmStore === null) {
    this.gsmStore = new GridStateMgrStore();
  }
  else {
    this.params.api.addEventListener("firstDataRendered", () => {
      let viewToLoad = this.gsmStore.initialView;
      if (viewToLoad != 'Default') {
        let entry = this.gsmStore.views.find(x => x.name == viewToLoad);
        if (entry) {
          // zone issue?
          setTimeout(() => { 
            this.params.api.applyColumnState({
              state: JSON.parse(entry.colState),
              applyOrder: true,
            });
            this.params.api.setFilterModel(JSON.parse(entry.filterModel));
          }, 0);
        }
        else {
          console.warn(`No entry found for ${viewToLoad}`);
        }
      }
   });
 }

}
